# Error connecting jmeter with sybase (15.7) with jtds-1.3.1

Tags: jmeter, sybase, jtds

I am trying to connect Apache Jmeter (5.2.1) with a Sybase 15.7 Database, the driver that I am using to make this connection is jtds-1.3.1.jar located in (c:/jmeter/lib/jtds-1.3. 1.jar) and when executing the test plan I have the following error:

```
2020-12-01 23: 38: 15,100 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread [Thread Group 1-1,6, main]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.isValid (JtdsConnection.java:2833) ~ [jtds-1.3.1.jar: 1.3.1]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid (DelegatingConnection.java:874) ~ [commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar: 2.5.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate (PoolableConnection.java:270) ~ [commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar: 2.5.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection (PoolableConnectionFactory.java:389) ~ [commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar: 2.5.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory (BasicDataSource.java:2398) ~ [commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar: 2.5.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory (BasicDataSource.java:2381) ~ [commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar: 2.5.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource (BasicDataSource.java:2110) ~ [commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar: 2.5.0]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection (BasicDataSource.java:1563) ~ [commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar: 2.5.0]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement $ DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection (DataSourceElement.java:361) ~ [ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar: 5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection (DataSourceElement.java:197) ~ [ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar: 5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample (JDBCSampler.java:79) ~ [ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar: 5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling (JMeterThread.java:627) ~ [ApacheJMeter_core.jar: 5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage (JMeterThread.java:551) ~ [ApacheJMeter_core.jar: 5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler (JMeterThread.java:490) ~ [ApacheJMeter_core.jar: 5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run (JMeterThread.java:257) ~ [ApacheJMeter_core.jar: 5.2.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2020-12-01 23: 38: 15,104 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-12-01 23: 38: 15,105 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning (false, * local *)
```

[image]

- DATA BASE URL: jdbc: jtds: sybase: //XX.XXX: XXX.XX: XXXX / portal
- JDBC Driver Class: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
- I rule out that it is a communication problem since on the same server I have Data Source configured with which I can make queries to the Sybase DB from an application

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot to add the [Validation Query](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

> (String) The SQL query that will be used to validate connections from this pool before returning them to the caller. If specified, this query does not have to return any data, it just can't throw a SQLException. The default value is null. If not specified, connections will be validation by the isValid() method. Example values are SELECT 1(mysql), select 1 from dual(oracle), SELECT 1(MS Sql Server)

Given you're using the JDBC Driver suitable for both MSSQL and Sybase you can try out `SELECT 1` as the validation query:

[image]

given other parameters are correct it should resolve your issue:

[image]

More information: [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)